# using sass to generate RTL & LTR css files in Omega 4

Tags: drush, theming

is there any convenient way of using Omega 4 to compile rtl and ltr css files automatically. I mean something like [this](http://anasnakawa.github.io/bi-app-sass/) or [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/manage-rtl-css-sass-grunt/), but for drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you define as being convenient.

The SASS part is easy, since sass support is already setup in Omega. You just need to setup some sort of a sass structure to write the CSS.

To change the language settings, you'll want to invoke the template_preprocess_html() function to override the html that's rendered.
[function template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

Comment: thank you, but I'm very lazy and I found simplest answer, although I couldn't find anything on the net.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer! no need to do any sass related work. I was working with layouts, and all I did was adding a file named `mylayoutname.layout-rtl.scss` under `sass/layouts/mylayoutname/` solved my problem :) it compile automatically to appropriate css file without any hassle.